# How to fix "Undefined function 'network' for input arguments of type 'double'" error?

Tags: matlab, som

i am trying to run the following commands

`x = simplecluster_dataset;
net = selforgmap([8 8]);
net = train(net,x);
view(net)
y = net(x);
classes = vec2ind(y);`

from [SOM Example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/selforgmap.html) in Matlab R2015a, but it is continuously showing me an error

`Error in selforgmap>create_network (line 110)
  net = network(1,1,0,1,0,1);

Error in selforgmap (line 74)
    net = create_network(param);

Error in nueralNet (line 2)
net = selforgmap([8 8]);`. 
I am trying to implement Self organizing maps in Matlab. Please help me out. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably don't have the Neural Networks toolbox installed.  `network` is part of that toolbox.  If you don't have it, unfortunately you can't run that function.

Comment: I can see the neural network buttons in above Apps tab. But, i am a new user so is there any way to verify that toolbox is there or not ?

Comment: Type in `ver` and see if the Neural Network Toolbox is listed.

Comment: Neural Network Toolbox                                Version 8.3        (R2015a), its there

Comment: When you're running your your code, do you have a **variable** called `network` somewhere?  Please update your question to include **all** of the code that you're using before calling `selforgmap`.

Comment: no i do not have network variable. I am following the this link for learning SOM networks http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/selforgmap.html

Comment: That's pretty weird.  I ran that same code and I got the result in the documentation.  Try doing `clear all;`, then try the code again.

Comment: not working :(  .  please check i just inserted the whole error log in the question.

Comment: I'm sorry for your troubles.  I can't seem to reproduce your error.  I'm running R2014a on Windows 7 64-bit and it works for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73539/discussion-between-nomi-and-rayryeng).

Comment: What does `which network` return?

Comment: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\toolbox\nnet\nnet\@network\network.m  % network constructor, Has no license available

Comment: Oops.  I guess you have the Neural Networks toolbox, but you don't have access to that particular function.  Are you running MATLAB on a trial basis?

Comment: Yup right  am using it on trial basis!

Comment: @Nomi - There we go.  On a trial basis, you have access to only **some** features in each toolbox.  You only get the full thing if you decide to buy it.

Comment: oooops ,.. thank u at least we have figured it out :)

Comment: No worries.  Sorry that this didn't go the way you planned!  Good luck!